# How to add a new key and value to an existing object in an array (Angular)

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object, interface

I want to push a new key and corresponding value to an already existing object. My object is returned after subscribing to a WEB API endpoint. Within the object returned, I want to add a "QuantityOnHand" key and value. I have attempted the following, however, it is not as I want it.

```
branchProduct: BranchProduct;
```

```
getProductByName() {

     const productName = this.addProductForm.get('product')?.value;

     const quantity = this.addProductForm.get('quantity')?.value;

     this.branchService.getProductByName(productName).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      this.branchProduct = resp;
      this.branchProduct.QuantityOnHand = quantity;
      console.log(this.branchProduct);
     })

   }
```

The "branchProduct" interface class is as follows:

```
export interface BranchProduct {
  BranchId: number;
  ProductId: number;
  ProductTypeName: string;
  ProductName: string;
  QuantityOnHand: number;
  BaselineQuantity: number;
}
```

After assigning a value to the QuantityOnHand attribute, the object is logged as follows:

[image]

Would it be possible to set the QuantityOnHand as an actual additional attribute of the aforementioned object after the object is created? I have tried setting "branchProduct" as an array and pushing the value of the quantity through to it, however, I had no success doing so.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It seems like `getProductByName` returns an array, why is that? Can it return many products? If so, do you want to assign QuantityOnHand to all products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the picture it's showing that branchProduct data is in 0 index of array. If branchProduct data always be one record on 0 index then you can fix it like.

```
getProductByName() {
     const productName = this.addProductForm.get('product')?.value;
     const quantity = this.addProductForm.get('quantity')?.value;
     this.branchService.getProductByName(productName).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      this.branchProduct = resp;
      this.branchProduct[0].QuantityOnHand = quantity;
      console.log(this.branchProduct);
     })

   }
```

Other wise you need to a implement a loop to modify the data.

```
const branchProductArray = []
branchProductObj.map((product, index) => {
   let productObject = {... product };
    productObject.QuantityOnHand = quantity;
    branchProductArray.push(productObject)

})
console.log(branchProductArray). //will be desire result.
```

Comment: I'd probably do `this.branchProduct = resp[0]` so the type doesn't need to be changed

Answer (score 1):

this.branchProduct is an array.

```
  this.branchProduct[0].QuantityOnHand = quantity;
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

Use spread operator

this.branchProduct = {...resp, quantityonHand:quantity}

Comment: Would you mind perhaps elaborating? I have added your answer to where I initially set this.branchProduct equal to resp, however, it displays the object similarly as to how I had it initially, However, now on top of that, it has the object array set as follows: `{0: {...}, quantityOnHand: 4}`